# MySQL only returning one result. Im Baffled

Tags: php, mysql

Here is te code:

```
<?php

//Starting session

session_start();

//Includes mass includes containing all the files needed to execute the full script
//Also shows homepage elements without customs

require_once ('includes/mass.php');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if (isset($username))

{   

//Query database for the users networths

$sq_l = "SELECT * FROM user";

$sql_query_worth = mysql_query($sq_l);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))

      {

         $dbusername = $row['username'];


      } 

      echo $dbusername;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're echoing outside of the loop. So it's only echoing the last row. Put that echo statement inside your while loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all usernames, then the echo statement should be within the while loop, eg.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))
  {
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    echo $dbusername;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using this portion of code :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))
{
     $dbusername = $row['username'];
} 

echo $dbusername;
```

Which means **only the name of the last user will be `echo`ed** :

- On each iteration of the loop, the username is stored in `$dbusername`
- But that variable's content is only echoed aftezr the loop

  - which means only the last value of `$row['username']` will be echoed.

If you want to output each usename, **you shoud put the `echo` inside the loop**, and not after :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query_worth))
{
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    echo $dbusername . '<br />';
}
```

And, with that, each name of each user should be `echo`ed ;-)